# Create an object that represents the differences in values between two other objects

Tags: c#, reflection

Assume the following class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

I would like to compare two instances of `MyEntity`, and create a new `MyEntity` instance that contains only the differences in values between the two other instances. Properties that are equal will result a `null` value in the new object.

for example, the I would like the following code:

```
MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Doh" };
MyEntity entity2 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "The Great" };
MyEntity diffEntity = CreateDiffEntity(entity1, entity2);  // TODO
```

to result with the following `diffEntity` values:

```
{
    FirstName: null,
    LastName: "The Great"
}
```

We can assume that all properties are nullable.

In case the values don't match, the new object should contain the value of the second object's property.

Please assume I have many types of entities, with different properties definitionsm
So I need a solution that can be used on other class types than `MyEntity`, and that won't require changes when new properties are added to the classes.

The final goal is to enable a client mobile application to send a DTO that contains only the changes made to an entity, to a ASP.NET MVC WebAPI server application.

How can this be properly done?

Comment: Have you already tried anything and get stuck, or just posted a question and think someone will do everything for you? :)

Comment: the diffEntity will take the value of the second entity if they do not match...?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question, you could do this in the class constructor, comparing the values of `entity1` and `entity2`. Have you tried anything at all or is this just a homework question?

Comment: Yes, I tried, with Automapper. but I would like to have a cleaner approach, so I didn't post any code.

Comment: the diffEntity will take the value of the second entity if they do not match

Comment: [Reflection](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2007/08/03/use-reflection-to-compare-the-properties-of-two-objects/)

Comment: Suppose you want to change a property to `null`. Your approach does not appear to allow that. You might want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big problem with this whole approach: you can't set anything to `null`. You should probably just be sending the full entity or, if you have interface(s) that only allow editing a subset of the properties, make a DTO for each interface with just the changes that can happen there.

---

Anyway, just because it was ripe for some easy improvement, this is a generic, and slightly modified, solution based on [BrianV's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342332/781792). (using `object.Equals` instead of `!=` allows for things to be compared by their values, not just their identities)

```
public T Compare<T>(T first, T second) where T : new()
{
    T result = new T();
    Type t = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoList =  t.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfoList)
    {
        object value1 = propertyInfo.GetValue(first, null);
        object value2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(second, null);

        if (!object.Equals(value1, value2))
            propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value2, null);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use it like:

```
MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Doh" };
MyEntity entity2 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "The Great" };
MyEntity diffEntity = Compare(entity1, entity2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Reflection to solve this. The basic gist of it is:

```
    public void Compare(object first,object second, object result)
    {
        Type t = first.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoList =  t.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfoList)
        {
            object value1=  propertyInfo.GetValue(first, null);
            object value2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(second, null);

            if (value1 != value2)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value1, null);
            }
            else
            {
               propertyInfo.SetValue(result, null, null);
            }

        }
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
MyType result = new MyType();
Compare(object1,object2, result);
```

It could be used as an extension  method or a member on one of your entities.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
    static public T CreateDiffEntity<T>(T entity1, T entity2) where T : new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var valuePropertyEntity1 = property.GetValue(entity1);
            var valuePropertyEntity2 = property.GetValue(entity2);
            if (!valuePropertyEntity1.Equals(valuePropertyEntity2))
                property.SetValue(result, valuePropertyEntity2);
            else
                property.SetValue(result, null);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue like this:

```
public MyEntity CreateDiffEntity(MyEntity entity1, MyEntity entity2) {
    MyEntity diff = new MyEntity();
    diff.FirstName = !entity1.FirstName.equals(entity2.FirstName) ? entity2.FirstName : string.Empty;
    diff.LastName = !entity1.LastName.equals(entity2.LastName) ? entity2.LastName : string.Empty;
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: You want `null`, not `string.Empty`. See OP's example output.

Comment: @tnw yepp, but this is just code example. OP can replace to null by itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the object initializer

```
MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Doh" };
MyEntity entity2 = new MyEntity() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "The Great" };

MyEntity diffEntity = new MyEntity
     {
         FirstName = (entity1.FirstName == entity2.FirstName) ? null : entity2.FirstName,
         LastName = (entity1.LastName == entity2.LastName) ? null : entity2.LastName
     };
```

Comment: I need a solution that can be used on other types than `MyEntity`, and that won't require changes when new properties are added to the classes

Comment: @Liel Then Brian's solution may be what you're looking for.